# I am getting a Error in this program with output

Tags: python-3.x, oop

This is a program from leetcode. when I executed this code on my computer at that time it was showing no errors. but when I run the same code in leetcode I started getting this error along with the output.

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self ,nums,target):
        self.nums = []
        self.target = target
        self.solution = []

    def check():
        for i in nums :
            if -10**9 <= nums[i] <= 10**9 :
                print("ok")
            else :
                sys.exit()
        if -10**9 <= target <= 10**9 :
            print("ok")
        else :
            sys.exit()

    try :
        def twosum(self):
            if  2 <= len(nums) <= 10**5 :
                for x in nums :
                    for y in nums :
                        if y != x and x+y == target :
                            solution = []
                            solution.append(nums.index(x))
                            solution.append(nums.index(y))
                            print("Because nums[" + str(nums.index(x)) + "] + nums[" + str(nums.index(y)) + "] == " + str(target) + ", we return" , solution)
                            return solution
                            break
                        else :
                            continue
    except :
        print("An exception occured")



nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
target = 4
demo = Solution(nums,target)
print(demo.twosum())
```

I am getting the needed output :

```
    Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1]
    [0, 1]
```

But I am also getting an error :

> TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'nums' and 'target'
> ret = Solution().twoSum(param_1, param_2)
> Line 62 in _driver (Solution.py)
> _driver()
> Line 73 in  (Solution.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error output, the `leetcode` driver program appears to be wanting to call your code with:

```
ret = Solution().twoSum(param_1, param_2)
```

In other words, it wants to construct your class with *no* parameters, then call a specific function in your class to do the work, passing the parameters into *that* function.

That means you'll have to provide something like:

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def twosum(self, nums, target):
        # Do your grunt work here.
```

---

And, if you want to use that exception, it should be *inside* the `twosum` function. The way you have it now is that the `try/except` is active during *creation* of the `twosum` function, not while *running* the function.

---

Additionally, you should get rid of, or adjust, your own driver code - that's why you're seeing the output you expect. But `leetcode` doesn't *want* you to do that, it just wants you to provide the class so *its* driver can call it.

There's a good chance it will simply import your file then call your function, so you can use the `__name__` trick to use your driver code if you run it normally, or theirs if they import it.

With all that, you'll probably end up with something like:

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def twosum(self, nums, target):
        if  2 <= len(nums) <= 10**5:
            for x in nums:
                for y in nums:
                    if y != x and x+y == target:
                        solution = []
                        solution.append(nums.index(x))
                        solution.append(nums.index(y))
                        return solution

if __name__ == "__main__": # don't run if you get imported.
    nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    target = 4
    demo = Solution(nums, target)
    print(demo.twosum())
```

Keep in mind I have no idea if your `twosum` function is doing what it's meant to do, I just tidied up the unnecessary stuff like `break` after `return`. But that should be a good basis for testing your code based on what `leetcode` needs from you.

Answer (score 0):

We would commonly solve it using a dictionary:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        indices = {}
        for index, num in enumerate(nums):
            if target - num in indices:
                return indices[target - num], index
            indices[num] = index
```

- memory O(N)
- runtime O(N)

---

You can also see the solutions [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/solution/)